# Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver for RDS postgres connection-Liquibase

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, jdbc, amazon-rds, liquibase

I am trying to connect to RDS Postgres from Liquibase.
Maven dependency is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.aws.rds</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-postgresql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not using properties file as the credentials are confidential and I cannot put them in properties file.
hence calling using command line

```
-liquibase --url:jdbc:postgressql://xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database_name --username = $username --password = $password --changeLogFile=changelog_aurora.xml update
```

Also tried:

```
-liquibase --url:jdbc:postgressql://xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/database_name --username = $username --password = $password --changeLogFile=changelog_aurora.xml --driver=org.postgressql.Driver update
```

I am getting below error:

> Unexpected error running liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException:Cannot
> find database driver: org.postgres.Driver

Please help me here. Do I need to install Postgres dependency as well? If so what should be the version? should it match with AWS RDS Postgres?

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but the proper JDBC URL prefix for PostgreSQL is `jdbc:postgresql:` (one **s**). In any case, please provide a [mre]. The error suggests you do not have the PostgreSQL JDBC driver on the classpath, so whatever you're doing, it isn't adding the driver to the classpath (or it is the wrong driver).

Answer (score 1):

I have following recommendations for you:

- You can download Postgre JDBC driver file from [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) if you haven't already or if you don't have JAVA installed and configured.
- Preferably keep your `postgresql-<version>.jar` file in the same folder where your changelog file is OR add path ([ref](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/using-the-liquibase-installer)) OR use `--classpath=path:anotherPath` with your commandline to indicate where should liquibase go and look for the Postgre JDBC driver file.
- Also if you are familiar with AWS SSM, you can keep all your secrets in SSM and read at runtime from within your property file (FYI)